# In Model file DateTime data type is storing UTC format. Is it possible to store in IST format?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In Model file (Hyperledger), `DateTime` data type is by default storing values in UTC format, but I want to store in IST format.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't store IST time in Hyperledger when you use the `DateTime` DataType. But if you want to Store IST formate than you need to use a `String` DataType.